# shell script - Unable to execute Java with parameters

Tags: shell-script

I have written a shell script that will take a parameter, pass that parameter to Java command. But I get error during the execution.

Here is the script:

```
#The script takes an input, the file name to be styled and executes the java program based on it

echo "Hello World"
echo "The parameter passed is $1"
cd ~/CStyler/java/
`javac Main.java`
`java Main $1`
```

The error I get:

```
Hello World
The parameter passed is hello
CStyler.sh: 7: CStyler.sh: The: not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577181/shell-script-and-java-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code  :

```
java YourApp "$1"
```

And run your code like this :

```
./app.sh your_argument
```

Comment: Yup got it! So what are these `` for?

Comment: excuse me what ?

Comment: In some shell scripts they execute the ls command like this `ls`, I asked what does these `` do?

Comment: it do nothing for me !

Comment: They are used like a variable for what a command returns, example `cd \`pwd\`` would `cd` to the current directory (which you are already in, but i couldn't think of an example).